# In scala3/dotty. Why is it impossible to mix in a type definition with constraint?

Tags: scala, type-systems, scala-3, dotty

In some cases it make sense to reuse a type constraint in both refinement and definition. E.g. the following definitions for `Thing1` & `Thing2` should be extensionally equivalent:

```scala
object TypeMixin {

  trait Thing {

    type TT
  }

  type ThingAux[T] = Thing { type TT = T }

  object Thing1 extends Thing {
    type TT = Int
  }

  object Thing2 extends Thing with ThingAux[Int]
}
```

`Thing2` has less boilerplate, but won't be compiled properly:

```
TypeMixin.scala:16:36: com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.TypeMixin.Thing{TT = Int} is not a class type
one error found
```

My question is: what's the repercussion of allowing the type system to resolve `Thing2`? What's the counter-example for which this syntax will causes some unsound definition?

Comment: I guess you're confusing subtyping and inheritance. This is not a type-system issue. There is no problem to consider a subtype of `Thing with ThingAux[Int]`. Just not all types are class types. For example `Thing with ThingAux[Int]` is not because `ThingAux[Int]` is not. And that's written in the error message. Child constructor has to call parent constructor. And `ThingAux[Int]` doesn't have any. You can't call `new ThingAux[Int]` although you can call `new Thing { type TT = Int }`. In Scala you can have `=:=`-equal types one of which is a class type and the other is not.

Comment: For `trait A[T]` you can have `<: A[Int] with A[String]` but you can't have `extends A[Int] with A[String]`, you can have `<: Int` but you can't have `extends Int`.

Comment: Classes is something present in bytecode. `Thing` is present in bytecode but `ThingAux` is not.

Comment: Agreed, but what's the consequence of automatically generating the syntax of Thing2 from Thing1? type ThingAux can't be JVM class file but can be stored as auxiliary manifest metadata

Comment: Type definition won't have any constructor which makes mixin even easier

Comment: A language should be kept simple enough and consistent. There should be strong reasons to invent some irregular syntax for a specific case. Try to formulate what kind of inheritance you'd like to allow (not only for this specific case). This should generalize existing [spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html). Would you like to allow `type A; class B extends A`? How does it look like in bytecode? How does it look like in Java (and other JVM-based languages) because of Scala-Java interop?

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues https://contributors.scala-lang.org/c/language-design/9

Comment: What you find easy to do is not necessarily what language designers find easy to do or desirable, at least at certain point of language development. Currently, it is not possible to extend `type`  even if it is known to alias to a `trait` or `class`, so you can use `Aux` pattern in type signatures but not in class definition (extends/with).